# GPU Rendering with Mac Book Pro with AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB?

Tags: rendering

I just bought the mac book pro with the AMD Radeon R9 M370X. Unfortunately rendering is quite slow. I've read in different forums that i need to switch to GPU in user preferences -> system and change to GPU computing on the right hand side of the screen. I did it but the rendering process is still slower than rendering with just cpu. Can sb tell me what i am doing wrong?
Thanks a lot!!
Marc

Comment: Something is still not right with Cycles bakes on AMD Radeon R9 M370X. The Macbook Pro (Mid 15) is freezing and just a hard reset will work,
even updated to MacOS Sierra.
That Bug is known since Month and it seems that no one cares at all.

Comment: @Symen Have you checked to see if this bug has been reported yet? If no, and this still occurs in the latest development version, you might consider [submitting a report yourself](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1377/599).

Answer (score 1):

With GPU rendering it's usually best to increase the tile size to about 256x256.
That way you're not going to-and-from CPU and GPU memory so much.

Answer (score 1):

there seems to be a big difference between nvidia graphic cards and amd graphic cards. Until recently Gpu rendering was only possible using the nvidia cards with cuda cores. Starting with blender 2.75 / 2.76 it should also be possible with OpenGL amd cards. But with restrictions, I believe. Being an apple fan myself it is still a bit of a mystery for me too with is exactly the status of blender Gpu rendering on Mac / amd hardware. It is my understanding that fast Gpu rendering is still a nvidia / Windows privilege

Comment: Fast GPU rendering is not an "nvidia / Windows privilege." It works just as well on Nvidia / Linux. I know it's easy to forget about us Linux users, but we do exist! :)

Comment: Most Blender developers work on Linux. Don't worry, we certainly won't forget about Linux users!